# Conflicting results python's ss.kstest vs R's ks.test (test if sample is uniformly distributed)

Tags: python, r, kolmogorov-smirnov, uniform-distribution

I am interested in checking if let's say a sample A (n=25) is uniformly distributed. Here is the way I'd check for that in Python:

```
import scipy.stats as ss
A=[9,9,9,4,9,6,7,8,9,4,5,2,4,9,6,7,3,4,2,4,5,6,8,9,9]
ss.kstest(A,'uniform', args=(min(A),max(A)), N=25)
```

Which returns: (0.22222222222222221, 0.14499771178796239), that is, with a p-value of ~0.15 the test can't reject that the sample A comes from an uniform distribution.

Now that's how I calculate the same in R:

```
A=c(9,9,9,4,9,6,7,8,9,4,5,2,4,9,6,7,3,4,2,4,5,6,8,9,9)
ks.test(A,punif,min(A),max(A))
```

The result: D = 0.32, p-value = 0.01195. With R one should reject the null hypothesis at the usual significance level of 0.05 (!!!)

If I read the documentation correctly, both functions perform a two-sided test as a default. Also, I get that the KS test is mainly intended for continuous variables, but can this explain the contrasting approximations produced by Python and R? Alternatively,  am I making some flagrant mistake on the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

The args for any cdf in scipy.stats are location and scale.  For the uniform distribution this is loc = minimum x value where the uniform density is 1 and the scale is the width of the interval where the uniform density is 1.  Using args = (min(A), max(A)-min(A)) in python will give the D-value given by R.

The p-value will be still be different.  This is due to the KS test not being robust to repeated values.  It is intended for use with continuous distributions and the expectation is that repeated y values do not occur.   Different algorithms are used to attempt to estimate p in the presence of repeated data.  If you rerun your code on another sample of data without repeats with the args set to loc and scale, you should get the same p-values in both R and Python.